# openGL rotation at multiple points

Tags: opengl

Basically i got some little confusion here regarding problem of rotation at multiple points with OpenGL and C++.

How to rotate the simple rectangular at point of rotation at (42,42) and (-42,42)? My box is moving from point (46,0) to (46,42) and make +90 degree rotation to (42,46) at point of rotation (42,42) (3 other points are not stated here because they are relative to the first point).

Then my box moves from (42,46) to (-42,46) and makes a simple 90 degree at (-42,42). Finally my box moves to point (-46,42). From (-46,42) moves to (-46,0).

I tried to use `glPushMatrix()`, `glTranslatef(42,42,0)`, `glRotatef(theta2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`, `glTranslatef(-42,-42,0)`. But it only worked for the first point of rotation. For next point of rotation it seemed not working. Any alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you not do the same negative translate to origin, rotate, translate back trick for the other points on your movement line?

Comment: Why? are they contracting with each other?

Comment: Your response confuses me.  Perhaps a translation issue?  What I mean is there is no reason that you can't rotate every object in the world with the same above trick.  Each translate, rotate, translate will be applied to the currently bound VBO - they are not dependent on each other.